# How to optimize materialized views when data volume and velocity increase in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, materialized-views

I created materialized views in Redshift. Data is growing incrementally day by day, will the performance (such as duration of query result) of these materialized views be affected as the size of the data volume and velocity increase? What should I optimize if it is affected?

Answer (score 0):

As things get bigger, queries in general will get slower.  However, the real question is if the query time (view refresh time) will increase disproportionally to the input data size.  Since materialized views are often used when the generating query is complex it is often the case.  So it is likely that things will slow noticeably as the data grows but how much will depend on your situation.

The important thing to ensure that the generating query is optimized.  Materialized views get used, at times, when people don't want to do the work of optimizing the query and it doesn't matter that the data is slightly out of current.  Then the data grows the the refresh time gets out of hand and THEN they need to do the optimization.  They bought some time which is often good.  If the generating query has looped joins or creates new data in processing it likely can be significantly optimized.